# Trouble in Proposition 6.7 in Atiyah MacDonald: Why is $N_i/N_{i+1}\subset M_i/M_{i+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 6.7 in Atiyah and Macdonald. I am stuck on the following part of the proof.

> Let $(M_i)$ be a composition series for $M$. Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Define $N_i=N\cap M_i$. Then $N_i/N_{i+1}\subset M_i/M_{i+1}$.

This should be simple but I cannot see what I am missing. Clearly $N_i\subset M_i$. Therefore clearly also $N_i/M_{i}\subset M_i/M_{i+1}$. But when we quotient $N_i$ by $N_{i+1}$ we are quoitenting by less stuff, so its not obvious why we have an inclusion.

Comment: If I'm understanding what $\subset$ means here correctly (that there is an injective map from $N_i/N_{i+1}$ into $M_i/M_{i+1}$, then isn't the following true: an element in $N_i/N_{i+1}$ is some coset $a + (N_{i+1})$, with $a \in N_i$. Just map this to $a + (M_{i+1}) \in M_i/M_{i+1}$. This is injective because if $a + (N_{i+1})$ and $b + (N_{i+1})$ are different cosets, then $a + (M_{i+1})$ and $b + (M_{i+1})$ must be different cosets as well. If not, there is some $m \in M_{i+1}$ so that $a + m = b$, but because $m = b -a \in N$, we also have $m \in N_{i+1}$, so $a = b$ in $N_i/N_{i+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the composition

$$N_{i} \xrightarrow{u} M_{i} \xrightarrow{\pi} M_{i}/M_{i+1}$$

where $u$ denotes inclusion, and $\pi$ denotes the canonical quotient morphism. The kernel of $\pi \circ u$ is $u^{-1}(\ker(\pi))$. Since $u$ is just the inclusion map, we have $u^{-1}(\ker(\pi)) = N_{i} \cap \ker(\pi)$. The kernel of $\pi$ is $M_{i+1}$, so we conclude that the kernel of $\pi \circ u$ is exactly $N_{i} \cap M_{i+1} = N_{i+1}$, and so $\pi \circ u$ descends to an injective map $N_{i}/N_{i+1} \to M_{i}/M_{i+1}$ by the universal property of the quotient, as desired.